# How to convert custom queries to magento query structures

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql

How can I use custom queries.I have a query for my custom module

```
 $query = "SELECT  * FROM  `XYZ_Productrequest` WHERE  product_sku = '$psku' and email = '$email' ";

I want to customize it as per the magento guideines.Help!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For converting this type of query, I have to call its model.

```
$model = Mage::getModel('module_name/model_name')->getCollection()
              ->addFieldToFilter('product_sku' , array ('eq' =>$psku ))
              ->addFieldToFilter('email' , array ('eq' =>$email ))
              ->getData();
print_r($model);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
$sel_qry ="SELECT  * FROM  `XYZ_Productrequest` WHERE  product_sku = '$psku' and email = '$email' ";
$selected = $readconnection->fetchAll($sel_qry);
```

this is the  another way to write query in magento

```
$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');

    $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('tablename'=>'XYZ_Productrequest'))->where('tablenametergallery.product_sku=?', $psku)->where('tablenametergallery.product_email=?', $email);
    $alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
```

third way

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('sku',$sku);
$order->getSelect()->join(array('yourtablename' => 'yourtablename'), 'main_table.sku=yourtablename.sku',
array('filed1' => 'field1','filed2' => 'filed2'));
```

Comment: Is this a proper way?
Actually I dont want to write whole query.

Comment: ok i will give you better query option with magento

Comment: update the answer check it

Comment: Can I have something like this?
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute'=> 'someattribute','like' => 'value'),
        array('attribute'=> 'otherattribute','like' => 'value'),
        array('attribute'=> 'anotherattribute','like' => 'value'),
    )
);

Comment: http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/ follow this how to create custom collection.

Comment: Okay Thanx for the response..

Comment: this table relate to product?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30427/discussion-between-vivek-khandelwal-and-qaisar-satti).